# Cannot get an Navigation Drawer to work (Android Studio)

Tags: android

I am new to development with Android Studio.

I am developing a `WebView` application that when user click in navigation, displays a new url based on item selected but I cannot get it to work...

here is some of my home Activity code.

```
    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
        
        when (menuItem.itemId) {
        
            R.id.nav_data -> binding.appBarHome.contentMain.webView.loadUrl("http://hurricanes.gov")
            R.id.nav_archive -> binding.appBarHome.contentMain.webView.loadUrl("ebay.com")
        }
        //drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        return true
    }
```

the app compiles but when clicked nothing happens.